# Relay Response URL Issue (Authorize.net)

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, onepage-checkout, authorize.net

I am having an issue where the checkout process on my store is not leading customers to a success page. Authorize.net advised me to add a relay response url to my account. Where can I find the relay response page? Is this anywhere in my theme files? Please help. I am on Magento 2.1

Comment: He needs a URL as far I understand. I'm having the same issue. Any solution to this @DevAnd?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146772)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My install of Magento 2.1.9 defaults to /authorizenet/directpost_payment/backendResponse

I have no idea where that's set.